# Playorm java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Tags: java, playorm

I tried to construct a basic ad hoc query example based on [A basic ad hoc query example](http://buffalosw.com/wiki/A-basic-ad-hoc-query-example)
.

But, I can't insert a Integer value. I think it is because of this piece of code:

```
private Class getStorageTypeAsClass() {
    switch (getStorageType())
    {
        case STRING:
            return String.class;
        case INTEGER:
            return BigInteger.class;
    }
}
```

My code:

```
package playorm;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.DbTypeEnum;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.NoSqlEntityManager;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.base.NoSqlEntityManagerFactory;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z3api.NoSqlTypedSession;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.KeyValue;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnCommonMeta;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnIdMeta;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboDatabaseMeta;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboTableMeta;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.TypedColumn;
import com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.TypedRow;

public class PlayOrm {
    private static NoSqlEntityManager mgr;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put(Bootstrap.AUTO_CREATE_KEY, "create");

        String clusterName = "Test Cluster";
        String seeds = "localhost:9160";
        String keyspace = "nosql";

        Bootstrap.createAndAddBestCassandraConfiguration(properties, clusterName, keyspace, seeds);
        NoSqlEntityManagerFactory factory = Bootstrap.create(DbTypeEnum.CASSANDRA, properties,null,null);
        mgr = factory.createEntityManager();
        DboDatabaseMeta metaDb = mgr.find(DboDatabaseMeta.class,
                DboDatabaseMeta.META_DB_ROWKEY);
        DboTableMeta meta = new DboTableMeta();
        meta.setup(null, "MyEntity", false);
        metaDb.addMetaClassDbo(meta);

        DboColumnIdMeta idMeta = new DboColumnIdMeta();
        idMeta.setup(meta, "idField", String.class, true);
        mgr.put(idMeta);

        DboColumnCommonMeta fieldDbo = new DboColumnCommonMeta();
        fieldDbo.setup(meta, "firstname", String.class, true, false);
        mgr.put(fieldDbo);
        DboColumnCommonMeta fieldDbo2 = new DboColumnCommonMeta();
        fieldDbo2.setup(meta, "lastname", Integer.class, true, false);
        mgr.put(fieldDbo2);

        mgr.put(meta);
        mgr.flush();

        NoSqlTypedSession session = mgr.getTypedSession();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            TypedRow typedRow = session.createTypedRow("MyEntity");
            typedRow.addColumn("firstname", "harry");
                        //**THE PROBLEM**
            typedRow.addColumn("lastname", new Integer(i));
            typedRow.setRowKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            session.put("MyEntity", typedRow);

            if(i > 1000 && (i % 10) == 0 ){
                session.flush();
                mgr.clear();
            }

        }
        session.flush();

}
```

There is no option to return Integer.class. So, it can't construct a Integer converter:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.NoSqlProxyImpl.invoke(NoSqlProxyImpl.java:96)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnCommonMeta_$$_javassist_1.convertToStorage2(DboColumnCommonMeta_$$_javassist_1.java)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.TypedRow.addColumn(TypedRow.java:99)
    at playorm.PlayOrm.main(PlayOrm.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.conv.Converters$BigIntegerConverter.convertToNoSqlImpl(Converters.java:89)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.conv.Converters$BaseConverter.convertToNoSql(Converters.java:138)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnMeta.convertToStorage2(DboColumnMeta.java:167)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.DboColumnCommonMeta_$$_javassist_1._d8convertToStorage2(DboColumnCommonMeta_$$_javassist_1.java)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: What exactly your code looks like?

Comment: yes, we need the example you are running.  We have around 110 unit tests and a lot of those test integers.  My guess is this one is user error BUT we need to add a better exception like "User did this wrong or something" so next person doesn't need to debug the issue.

Comment: Ok. The code is above. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

TypedRow is a special api and allows BigInteger, BigDecimal and String types right now.....These types however when stored are stored as the lowest bytes possible so an int value of 10 is stored as one byte.

out of curiosity, why not use a MyEntity.java class annotated with @NoSqlEntity instead???  In your case, using a POJO would seem more beneficial.

MyEntity.java can have any primitive types, int, double, etc. etc.

We thought you were using the entities as most use the entities to make development faster.

later,
Dean

Comment: I don't know which attributes the class will need. I would like to create the column family dynamically when the user of application wishes. Can I create the column family in this way using POJO?

Comment: Sometimes I use @NoSqlEmbedded private Map<STring, String> in my pojo as I know "part" of my column family, right?  That is feasible and I think some users have used @ NoSqlEmbedded private List<AnotherEntity> list; (both of those put all of that data in your row but are not exactly predefined then)

Comment: in case you were curious as well, if I have private Map<String, String> myMap; and I store keys a and b and c, then the column names end up being "myMap"."a" and "myMap"."b" and "myMap"."c" etc. etc. etc.  The values are naturally the values....you can supply your own converter if you have complex types for the value(and I think for the name as well too) though I have not experimented with that much